# Getting error while running flutter application using Android Studio

Tags: flutter

'''
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Exploration!',
       theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.lightGreen),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
   }
 }

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Space Exploration Planner"),
      ),
      body: Column(children: [
        Progress(),
        TaskList()
      ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Progress extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('You are this far away exploring the whole universe'
         ),
      LinearProgressIndicator(value: 0.0),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TaskList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TaskItem(label: "Load Rocket with Supplies"),
        TaskItem(label: "Launch Rocket"),
        TaskItem(label: "Circle the home planet"),
        TaskItem(label: "Head out to the first moon"),
        TaskItem(label: "Launch moon lander #1"),
      ],
    );
  }
 }

class TaskItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;

  const TaskItem({ Key key, @required this.label}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Checkbox(value: false, onChanged: null),
        Text(label),
      ],
    );
  }
 }
```

'''

> I tried this code but I'm getting following error:
> 62:24: Error: The parameter 'key' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'Key', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
> - 'Key' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart'
> Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
> const TaskItem({ Key key, @required this.label}) : super(key: key);
> ^^^
> lib/main.dart:62:44: Error: The parameter 'label' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
> Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
> const TaskItem({ Key key, @required this.label}) : super(key: key);

> How to solve this?
> Any changes I have to do?

Comment: Add `?` after `Key` to make it nullable `const TaskItem({ Key? key, @required this.label}) : super(key: key);`

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Exploration!',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.lightGreen),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Space Exploration Planner"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [Progress(), TaskList()],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Progress extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text('You are this far away exploring the whole universe'),
        LinearProgressIndicator(value: 0.0),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TaskList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        TaskItem(label: "Load Rocket with Supplies"),
        TaskItem(label: "Launch Rocket"),
        TaskItem(label: "Circle the home planet"),
        TaskItem(label: "Head out to the first moon"),
        TaskItem(label: "Launch moon lander #1"),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class TaskItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;

   TaskItem({required this.label});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [Checkbox(value: false, onChanged: null), Text(label)],
    );
  }
}
```

use this code I checked it and I found you don't use a required key in the constructor.

Comment: Still not working, now error is : Error: The parameter 'label' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type 'String', but the implicit default value is 'null'.
    Try adding either an explicit non-'null' default value or the 'required' modifier.
      const TaskItem({@required this.label});

Comment: did you try to make the label  value  accept a null value?

Comment: final String? label;